# Bypass "App has been blocked due to company policy" when downloading app

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-store

I bought a brand new, Windows 10, computer a few days ago. When setting up the mail app, I configured it to include my school emails. A little while later, I tried to download TeamViewer from the windows store but it gave me, "App has been blocked due to company policy." I figured it was my school email so I removed it and tried again with no luck. After a few hours of searching the web for answer, I only came up with "App has been blocked due to protection." What can I do to get access to windows store apps again? Note: I can open windows store but some apps are blocked by company policy.

Answer (score -1):

What version of Windows? Pro edition? Are you on a domain or workgroup? Is the new computer you bought brand new from factory or newly purchased? Try the below fix, after about 30 seconds it should reset Windows Store, and delete the cache. If this does not work and the none of the above applies it may be an authentication error in the network.  Advise of any custom internet settings that you may have applied that could possibly affect Windows Store from authenticating your device for download.

### Check if you are on a domain or workgroup

> Start>Type 'Control Panel' and Launch it>System and Security>System
>   Under Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings: Workgroup: ***(domain or workgroup)*** 
>   There are specific settings for each that may need configuring.
>
> ---

*-Check which port TeamViewer is using and change it to an alternate port.* (check your TeamViewer Documentation, only 3 ports are available by default)

*-Do you have any group policy restrictions applied?-*
-Verify if group policies are applied that may restrict access.
*-Troubleshoot the Windows Store App further.-* 
-I found similar troubleshooting steps at [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/this-app-has-been-blocked-due-company-policy/f1328070-7da9-44c0-8924-fdad7ef7a3bc)
*-Troubleshoot Windows App (below text copied from 'answers.microsoft')-*

> *-Have you tried running the troubleshooter for Windows Store Apps? If not, >follow the steps below:-*

```
-Go to Control Panel.
-In the Search box, type troubleshooting.
-Press Enter.
-Select Troubleshooting.
-Click Hardware and Sound.
-Select Windows Store Apps to launch the troubleshooter.
-Click the Advanced link and make sure that the Apply repair automatically option is selected.
Click Next to run the troubleshooter.
```

## Follow the rest of the guide provided in the link for additional Troubleshooting if needed. Here are a few more tips below.

-**Try several different Windows Store Apps with lower permissions and no network usage to see if it is blocking certain apps or all apps.**

-**Sign in to Microsoft, or Sign out delete browser cache, Sign back in.**

## Apply all Windows Updates

> Try updating Windows, do it a few times because Windows will lie at first.
>   *>**You may have to remove a specific update in order to get it working also from my previous experience years ago, search for a solution on this if needeed**

### Check the Firewall Settings

> Ensure there is no conflict with incoming/outgoing ports *(Windows Store uses port 51485 I believe) and that connections are correctly configured to deny or allow connections. 
>   Verify your LAN, VPN, Domain, Workgroup, Group Policy, User Acct Control settings are not restricting access

## To quickly apply policy updates by force in the cmd line.

> Start>Type 'cmd'>Right Click on 'cmd' launcher>Select 'Run as Admin'
>
> In the cmd line Type 'gpupdate -f' without the quotes for *"Group Policy Update-force"*

## BIOS, advanced settings are often overlooked

> Verify your *BIOS* settings for LAN settings, and power settings for WakeonLAN 'terminology may differ' *This is often overlooked and would actually be my starting point, but I'm assuming you may have already configured BIOS.*

## *If all else fails*

*>Research the topic further*

> Uninstall and Reinstall Windows Store App [Youtube-Reinstall Windows Store App Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQo53hvWy8Q)

## Power Down Completely after 'network, port changes' and Why

> I would suggest a *complete power down* when applying hardware changes,and would go as far as removing the battery of the laptop and holding the power button down for 10 seconds to drain the remaining charge. Dependent on certain power settings, wake on LAN, autostart etc. it is sometimes necessary to initiate a full power down (NOT RESTART) in order to get some settings/changes to apply, especially with network ports changes.

Try resetting Windows Store and the cache:

> Press the Windows Key
>   Type 'Run' to bring up the 'run command' 
>   Type 'WSReset.exe' and press 'Enter'

Comment: I am using a HP Elitebook 8470p with Windows 10 pro.

There is no option that says "LAN Proxy Server"

MSReset.exe comes up as not a program but WSReset.exe doesn't fix the problem

I haven't changed any network settings other than connecting to my home network. I have installed other apps successfully before TeamViewer.

Comment: @AustinKugler Please excuse the typo earlier on WSReset.exe.  If the install of TeamViewer was the prerequisite leading to this, it must me a network and/or port related setting that is conflicting with WinStore. I will update my original answer above.