# Bypass "App blocked due to company policy" in Windows 10 Store

Tags: windows-10, administrator, group-policy, windows-store-app

I've got a new PC with Windows 10 from my work in which I have a local user account as Administrator. I'm trying to install some apps through the Windows 10 Store but I get the message shown in the screenshot "App blocked due to company policy". Is there a way to bypass this policy as Administrator, it's really making the OS hard to use. I've searched other questions but the [only one](https://superuser.com/questions/1261776/bypass-app-has-been-blocked-due-to-company-policy-when-downloading-app) relevant I found wasn't very helpful.

[image]

EDIT:

Below is currently my `Store` configuration in the `Local Group Policy Editor`:

[image]

Comment: Also I added a snapshot with my Store configuration at the Local Group Policy Editor. Everything is set to Not Configured.

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately, `gdedit.msc` does not show you the policies in effect; it only shows any **locally** configured policies. Run `rsop` to view the *"Resultant Set of Policies"*. That will show you a view very similar to gpedit, but only includes nodes containing non-default policies - including those pushed down from the domain.

Comment: In addition to the edition of Windows.  Verify your region and language settings are correct and UAC is enabled